# Como seleccionar un dato en datagrid?

Tags: c#, sql-server

Tengo un datagrid cargado con un datatable y al hacerle click no me selecciona nada.

```
private void dgvClientes_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dgvClientes.Rows.Count > 0)
        {

            dgvClientes.Rows[dgvClientes.CurrentRow.Index].Selected = true;
            DataGridViewRow DR = (DataGridViewRow)dgvClientes.CurrentRow;
            inIDCliente = (Convert.ToInt32(DR.Cells[0].Value));
            this.btnModificar.Enabled = true;
            this.btnEliminar.Enabled = true;

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

En el if (dgvClientes.Rows.Count > 0) solo indicas que "si el datagrid tiene mas de una fila" ... y el evento cell click espera una instruccion para hacer ... puedes sacar las instrucciones fuera del if o indicar en que columna realizar dicha instruccion.
puedes ponerlo asi...

```
private void dgvClientes_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
          if (e.ColumnIndex == 0 || e.ColumnIndex == 2)
              {
                 dgvClientes.Rows[dgvClientes.CurrentRow.Index].Selected = true;
                 DataGridViewRow DR = (DataGridViewRow)dgvClientes.CurrentRow;
                 inIDCliente = (Convert.ToInt32(DR.Cells[0].Value));
                 this.btnModificar.Enabled = true;
                 this.btnEliminar.Enabled = true;
              }




    }
```

Ejecuta la instruccion al dar click en el la columna 0 ó la columna 2